# Powershell Invoke-Command & IISConfigCollection

Tags: powershell

I want to get Informations about IIS Application Pools from another Server.

This should be possible with Invoke-Command. But theres a behavior i do not unterstand...

When i execute on the local machine the script block looks like this:

```
# get the values recorded under Recycle
$ConfigSection = Get-IISConfigSection -SectionPath "system.applicationHost/applicationPools"
$SitesCollection = Get-IISConfigCollection -ConfigElement $ConfigSection
$Site = Get-IISConfigCollectionElement -ConfigCollection $SitesCollection -ConfigAttribute @{"name" = "$AppPool"}
$recycling = Get-IISConfigElement -ConfigElement $Site -ChildElementName "recycling"
$flags = $recycling.Attributes["logEventOnRecycle"].Value

$onRecycle = @{
    'Time'           = [bool]($flags -band 1)     # Specific Time
    'Requests'       = [bool]($flags -band 2)     # Request Limit Exceeded
    'Schedule'       = [bool]($flags -band 4)     # Regular Time Interval
    'Memory'         = [bool]($flags -band 8)     # Virtual Memory Limit Exceeded
    'IsapiUnhealthy' = [bool]($flags -band 16)    # Isapi Reported Unhealthy
    'OnDemand'       = [bool]($flags -band 32)    # Manual Recycle
    'ConfigChange'   = [bool]($flags -band 64)    # Application Pool Configuration Changed
    'PrivateMemory'  = [bool]($flags -band 128)   # Private Memory Limit Exceeded
}
```

This works, i can use this as `"$onRecycle.Time"`...

But no i want to get the Information from a Remote computer.

My first thought was to just wrap the whole thing into a $command variable. Of course it didnt work.. It generates the following errors:

> - Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ConfigElement'. The argument is
>     null. Provide a valid value for the argument, and then try running the
>     command again.
> - Cannot index into a null array.

Then i thought ill do it step for step. Starting with:

```
$s = "chvmes01"    
$command1 = { Get-IISConfigSection -SectionPath "system.applicationHost/applicationPools" }
    $ConfigSection = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $s -ScriptBlock $command1
```

This works and gets the desired information, but already on the next step there are troubles again:

```
$command2 = { param($ConfigSection)(Get-IISConfigCollection -ConfigElement $ConfigSection) }
$SitesCollection = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $s -ScriptBlock $command2 -ArgumentList $ConfigSection
```

Here i try to include the Variable $ConfigSection but its giving me the following error back:

> Cannot bind parameter 'ConfigElement'. Cannot convert the
>   "Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationSection" value of type
>   "Deserialized.Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationSection" to
>   type  "Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationElement".

I thought maybe the reason is that i need `Import-Module WebAdministration`, but it has no effect. Still the same error.. As already the second step doenst work i cant continue..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now i found the solution for my problem, thanks to @Kirill Pashkov who led me in the right direction!

It now looks like this:

```
$s = "chvmes01"
$AppPool = "DefaultAppPool"       

$command1 = {
param($AppPool)
Get-IISConfigSection -SectionPath "system.applicationHost/applicationPools" |
Get-IISConfigCollection |
Get-IISConfigCollectionElement -ConfigAttribute @{"name" = $AppPool} |
Get-IISConfigElement -ChildElementName "recycling"
}

$recycling = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $s -ScriptBlock $command1 -ArgumentList $AppPool

$flags = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $s -ScriptBlock {param($recycling)$recycling.RawAttributes.logEventOnRecycle} -ArgumentList $recycling

$command2 = {
    param($flags)
    @{
    'Time'           = [bool]($flags -band 1)     # Specific Time
    'Requests'       = [bool]($flags -band 2)     # Request Limit Exceeded
    'Schedule'       = [bool]($flags -band 4)     # Regular Time Interval
    'Memory'         = [bool]($flags -band 8)     # Virtual Memory Limit Exceeded
    'IsapiUnhealthy' = [bool]($flags -band 16)    # Isapi Reported Unhealthy
    'OnDemand'       = [bool]($flags -band 32)    # Manual Recycle
    'ConfigChange'   = [bool]($flags -band 64)    # Application Pool Configuration Changed
    'PrivateMemory'  = [bool]($flags -band 128)   # Private Memory Limit Exceeded
    }
}

$onRecycleLog = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $s -ScriptBlock $command2 -ArgumentList $flags
```

Finally i got the right output saved in the $onRecycleLog Variable which looks like this:
[image]

Thank you Kirill for your support!

Answer (score 1):

The `Get-IISConfigCollection` cmdlet gets a `ConfigurationCollection` object from either a `ConfigurationSection` or a `ConfigurationElement`.

It is advisable to not to assign this value to a parameter and pass it in the pipeline to the next cmdlet since Windows PowerShell cannot interpret this object. This is due to the fact that `ConfigurationCollection` implements IEnumarable and the pipeline processor enumrates each single element when used this way. Instead either pass the whole `Get-IISConfigCollection` cmdlet in the pipeline or pass it as a parameter.

Example:

```
$ScriptBlock= { Get-IISConfigSection -SectionPath "system.applicationHost/applicationPools" | Get-IISConfigCollection }
$SitesCollection = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $s -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock
```

Answer (score 0):

**Suggestion** : You can use Enter-PsSession command to enter in Remote Computer and then you can run commands over there.

**Enter-PSSession -ComputerName "Remote-Computer-name"**

** your Commands like local.

Comment: First a question about this: Do you know if your suggested way is faster in processing? as i already build my whole script on the base of invoke-command i would like to stay with this. But i realized that my script is a little slow now, so if i can gain speed with "Enter-PSSession", i could think about rewriting everything again

Comment: still you can use your script after entering in pssession.No need to change it

Invoke-Command -Command $command